# from where CopySwiftLibs gets executes and copies standard swift libraries? is there a way to avoid it?

Tags: swift, xcode

From where CopySwiftLibs gets executed? I am trying to avoid getting libswift*.dylib which gets copied through CopySwiftLibs, I see an option in xcode, which is "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries", but it is set to "No", but still libswift libraries gets copied to Contents/Frameworks/ of app. Is there a way yo avoid it?

Comment: is there a way to avoid these swift libraries to be copied in app?

Answer (score 0):

CopySwiftLibs phase calls `swift-stdlib-tool`. You can learn about its usage with this Terminal command:

> xcrun swift-stdlib-tool --help

There’s an option called `--source-libraries <path>` that defines where to copy the libraries from. Apparently, to prevent it from copying any libraries you can set that path to some empty or non-existent folder.

You can define custom `OTHER_SWIFT_STDLIB_TOOL_FLAGS` build setting for your target and set it to

> --source-libraries /dev/null

[image]